# Create node with .net in elasticsearch

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, elasticsearch

I have a elasticsearch db with one node and would like to create one more Node.
I use Elasticsearch Head to view the Nodes and Visualstudio  C# to create index and insert data.

I have been reading on the elasticsearch page: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/6.x/keeping-track-of-nodes.html 
but i seem to miss something to create the node. 
i tried this

```
 using Nest;
 public ActionResult CreateNode(){
   Elasticsearch.Net.Node node = new Elasticsearch.Net.Node(new 
    Uri("http://localhost:9200")){                
            MasterEligible = true,
            HoldsData = true,
            Name = "SecondNode" };
      //  node.Uri.Should().NotBeNull();   .Should doesn't work
      //  node.Uri.Port.Should().Be(9200);
        return View("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml");}
```